# How to use NOT in relational SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

when I select table like this: `select count(*) from products` is returning 12900 result.

I have a relational query that returns multiple table relation reult like this:

```
SELECT category.name, 
       manifacturer.name,
       supplier.name,
       product.name
FROM   products as product,
       suppliers as supplier, 
       manifacturers as manifacturer,
       categories as category
WHERE  product.sid=supplier.id AND
       product.manid = manifacturer.id AND
       product.catid = category.id
```

This query returns 12873 result,

So I can not find which data is not matched. How can I find this lost data? I used NOT query but did not return any result.

Comment: You have NULL's somewhere in product.sid, product.manid or product.catid.

Comment: Not related to the question but an alias is intended to give a new name to a table. When you alias the table as the same name it provides no benefit but requires more typing. And for what it is worth, there is no "i" in manufacturer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see that not matched records with FULL OUTER JOIN like this:

```
SELECT prod.id, rel.id FROM (
SELECT category.name, 
       manifacturer.name,
       supplier.name,
       product.name
FROM   products as product,
       suppliers as supplier, 
       manifacturers as manifacturer,
       categories as category
WHERE  product.sid=supplier.id AND
       product.manid = manifacturer.id AND
       product.catid = category.id
) as rel
FULL OUTER JOIN products as prod
ON rel.id = prod.id
```

So you can see null id and not null ids in list.

Answer (score 6):

First, you should learn to use proper, explicit `join` syntax:

```
SELECT category.name, manifacturer.name, supplier.name, product.name
FROM   products as product join
       suppliers as supplier
       on product.sid = supplier.id join
       manifacturers as manifacturer
       on product.manid = manifacturer.id join
       categories as category
       on product.catid = category.id;
```

Then if you want non-matches, switch to `left join` and look for non-matches in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT category.name, manifacturer.name, supplier.name, product.name
FROM   products as product left join
       suppliers as supplier
       on product.sid = supplier.id left join
       manifacturers as manifacturer
       on product.manid = manifacturer.id left join
       categories as category
       on product.catid = category.id
WHERE supplier.id IS NULL OR manifacturer.id IS NULL or category.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comments about aliasing above you should use the "newer" join syntax introduced in ANSI-92. Notice how much less code there is here for the same thing. The way you wrote your code all your joins were inner joins, since you want to return rows with no match I changed them to left joins.

```
SELECT c.name, 
       m.name,
       s.name,
       p.name
FROM products p
left join suppliers s on p.sid = s.id
left join manifacturers m on p.manid = m.id
left join categories c on p.catid = c.id
```

Answer (score -1):

Below Query returns those records whose products are not present in your Query :

```
SELECT *
FROM Products P
WHERE (P.sid,P.mainid,P.catid) NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT product.sid
    ,product.mainid
    ,product.catid
    FROM products AS product
        ,suppliers AS supplier
        ,manifacturers AS manifacturer
        ,categories AS category
    WHERE product.sid = supplier.id
        AND product.manid = manifacturer.id
        AND product.catid = category.id
    )
```